# Access Network Drive in Azure Databrick Notebook

Tags: databricks, mount, azure-databricks, network-drive, databricks-connect

I have a network drive that stores some files. I need to access these files via my Azure Databricks notebook. Any ideas?

I tried

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('\\\\<driveName>\\<DriveDIR>'): 
  for name in files: 
    print(os.path.join(root, name))
```

But this doesn't work in Azure

Best regards,
Sree